# How can we place the activity indication until we get the response from server side

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.I am doing one project in that there is a login screen when ever i am click submit button in login screen it will sends a request to server for validation after some time it will gives response i am showing that response in alert view to the user.But the actual problem is when ever user clicks the submit button i am placing some activity indicator using timer for 1sec but the response comes in 5sec so the activity indicator stops before 4sec.So,how can i place the activity indicator until the response comes from server side.If anybody knows this please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need show your "indicator" while the request isn't finish

you request needs to be async like this :

```
-(void) performCheckServer // YOUR FUNCTION 
{

    // Construct your request
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [connection start];

    // show your indicator
}

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
}

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //hide indicator
}

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
//hide indicator
}
```

Other solution : use Progress HUD

- https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

and use the function :

```
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myProgressTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

see here complete step y step tutorial

http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/03/09/activity-indicator-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing to make the indicator go away? You must be calling:

```
[yourIndicatorView stopAnimating]
```

or

```
[yourIndicatorView removeFromSuperview]
```

or

```
yourIndicatorView.alpha = 0.f (<-- bad idea)
```

... or *something* that makes the activity indicator vanish.

You should move that call into the NSURLConnection callbacks that indicate the request has finished.